# How to prevent a button from stretching in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

For the past couple of hours, I have been trying to figure out why is the button that I have created keeps stretching itself when I am trying to set horizontal constraint. as seen in the following photo I have set the aspect ratio constraints to prevent the button from stretching (I have tried deleting the aspect ratio but it still yield the same result) [image: Before setting the horizontal constraint]

The moment I add an alignment constraint (In order to always keep the button in the middle) I am greeted with eh the following horror.

[image: After setting horizontal allignement constraint]

This is sadly not the first time that something like this is happening to me, could someone please explain me why is this happening and how I can possibly prevent it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You have red lines and a red error disclosure in your view hierarchy; your button does not have sufficient constraints. It needs sufficient constraints that autolayout can work out x,y width and height

Comment: @Paulw11 The problem is the suggested constraints it still stretches it out

Comment: "suggested constraints" from Interface Builder are rarely the constraints you want.  You need to think about where you want the button and what its size should be.  Do you want a fixed size?  If so, set a width or height constraint.  Do you want it to be a fixed distance from each edge of the screen?  If so, set leading and trailing constraints.  Where do you want the button to be located?  You need to set its top/bottom or center location as required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button must have at least width or height constraint , with aspect ratio , so it can't be stretched

Comment: the problem if I set a width and height then the button will never change its size ( which will cause a problem depending on the phone a given person is using e.g. iPhone 4 or iPhone X)

Comment: set a width proportional to screen

Comment: Do you do this in storyboard or viewcontroller

Comment: in storyboard control drag from the button to the main View and select **Egual-Widths** then click the constraint and change it's multiplier to say 0.5 , so button width will be half any screen

Comment: You can also give button XY = view XY, button width <= some fixed points (200) and aspect ratio=1:1. Width = 0.5 multiplier of screen is the best though with centering and fixed aspect ratio is better though.